# How can I make a ball glow and cast light?

Tags: lighting, unity, glow

I want to make my ball glow and cast light on other objects in the scene.
The scene is generated at run time so I believe baking is out of the question.
Emission materials work only when the object casting the glow/light is static.

Comment: The ball is controlled by the player

Comment: I'm trying to build for android.
I switched my platform to PC and checked but it's not any different.

Comment: Sorry. I thought this was dedicated to Unity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use the emmisive property alone, that will simply cause the object to appear. If this is something you are positive you want (And realize that it may affect your FPS, especially if you have a large number of these objects), I would use a combination of two techniques:

1. Use the emissive property. This will make the object appear lit even in a dark scene.
2. Attach a light source to the object. Make sure to use the same color as the emissive property.
3. You might need to turn down the albedo of the object as well.

Here's an example of me doing just this. Note the wall behind is black, I turned off the skybox illumination, and it is the only light source enabled.

[image]

Comment: I'm only going to use two of these balls. Also the rest of the map doesn't have any light sources. If that doesn't work well. I'll use an additive blend on the ball.

Comment: In that case, you should be more than fine to take the approach that I outlined.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it out on my phone(Moto G 1st Gen) and it seems to work fine.

Comment: nice answer. :)